# Communigate: writing rules

Tags: email-server, spam

We have Communigate on our mail server. Recently we moved to Dr.Web antivirus + antispam. When it checks mail for spam it writes spam score in 'X-Spam-Level: *****', where number of '*' signifies the spam score.

How to match these '*' in communigate rules? I've tried * for single '*', but it doesn't work.

Comment: Consider asking [Communigate Product Support](https://support.communigate.com/tickets/) primarily, they're more likely to know than we are.  Communigate strikes me as something of a niche product, compared to say, asking questions about `exim` or `postfix`

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: yep. I've used a tool from my AV software(Dr.Web) to rewrite the '*' to 'x'. The external rewriting solution was proposed my Communigate Support.